# Solving $\mathbf{z^4 = u}$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the equation $\mathbf{z^4 = u}$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is a complex number given by $\mathbf{u = 16i}$. I know that $\mathbf{r}$ (the magnitude of $\mathbf{u}$) is $\mathbf{16}$, but I'm not sure how to find $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ (the angle of $\mathbf{u}$ in polar coordinates), and how to get the angles in this picture (denoted with a minus sign):

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What direction is $i$ pointing?

Comment: In the complex plane, the complex number $i$ is represented by a point on the vertical axis, above the origin. This means that $i$ is pointing directly upwards on the complex plane. To find the angle of the complex number $u = 16i$, we can use the fact that $i$ is pointing upwards on the complex plane. The angle of $u$ is then simply the angle that $u$ makes with the positive real axis, which in this case is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians or $90^\circ$. Correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @JohnDouma How do we get the - angles, or why do we write it like that?
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/903430332324405288/1054249713324544030/Skarmavbild_2022-12-19_kl._05.11.42.png

Comment: There is an identity your teacher should have taught you: $e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$. This is what relates the rectangular form $a+ib$ to the polar form $re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @John Douma I am still not sure why we use negative angles.

Comment: $\frac{7\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @JohnDouma Is this true?

"if we used an angle outside of the range -π to π, the arctan function might not return a value that is consistent with the angle of the complex number in the complex plane. For example, if we used the angle 5π/4 to represent the complex number -1 + i, the arctan function would return a different value:

angle = atan(imaginary part / real part) = atan(1 / -1) = 3π/4

This result is not consistent with the angle of the complex number in the complex plane, because it is not between -π and π."

Comment: Use $-5\pi/4$. The trigonometric functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ have a period of $2\pi$. So $3\pi/4-2\pi=-5\pi/4$

Comment: @Andrei I'm having some trouble memorizing the trig values up to π/2 for cos, sin, and tan. I don't have the best memory, and I'm struggling to remember all of the values.

I remember that there was a triangle you could look at to help memorize the values, but I can't seem to find it or remember exactly how it works. Does anyone have any tips or tricks for memorizing these values? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of this sort of [unit circle](https://dr282zn36sxxg.cloudfront.net/datastreams/f-d%3A43392176e093fa07f39e1f3687226d4d751b809be928c16abac5dcb3%2BIMAGE_TINY%2BIMAGE_TINY.1) diagram? Best way to memorize these special values is with plenty of practice with trigonometry.

Comment: With the unit circle in the previous comment, draw perpendiculars to the x and y axes from every point. You will form right angle triangles. All you need to remember are the following: 1) $360^\circ=2\pi$ radians. 2) The hypotenuse for every right angle triangle is $1$. 3) For $45^\circ$, the sides are equal. 4) For $30^\circ$, the opposite side is half of the hypotenuse. Everything else can be derived using Pythagoras' theorem and the definition of $\sin, \cos, \tan$ in a right angle triangle.

Comment: Please, avoid the abuse of bolt fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly from the property $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$, we get
$$\left|z^4\right|=\left(|z|\right)^4=|16i|=16.$$
Since $|z|$ is a positive real, the only solution is $|z|=2$.

Then from the property $\mathrm{Arg}(z_1z_2)=\mathrm{Arg}(z_1)+\mathrm{Arg}(z_2)$ we get
$$\mathrm{Arg}\left(z^4\right)=4\mathrm{Arg}(z)=\mathrm{Arg}(16i)+2k\pi=\frac\pi2+2k\pi.$$
We only need to solve for $\mathrm{Arg}(z)\in[0,2\pi)$. Possible solutions include
$$\mathrm{Arg}(z)=\frac18\pi,~\frac58\pi,~\frac98\pi,~\frac{13}8\pi.$$
Therefore, all solutions for $z$ of the function $z^4=16i$ are
$$z=2e^{i\pi/8},~z=2e^{5i\pi/8},~z=2e^{9i\pi/8},~z=2e^{13i\pi/8}.$$
expressing in exponential form.

Answer (score 1):

If we didn't have de Moivre's results available, the solutions to the equation are still within reach to us.  We can factor
$$ z^4 \ \ = \ \ 16i \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z^4 \ - \ 16i \ \ = \ \ (z^2 \ + \ 4·\sqrt{i} ) \ · \ (z^2 \ - \ 4·\sqrt{i} ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
which already suggests that there are four complex numbers to be found.

We may  propose complex numbers of the form $ \ \alpha + i·\beta \ $ as representing $ \ \sqrt{ \ 0 \ + \ 1·i} \ \ , \ $ with $ \ \alpha \ , \ \beta \ $ being real numbers, which requires that
$$ ( \ \alpha \ + \ i·\beta \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ \alpha^2 \ + \ i·2·\alpha·\beta  \ + \ i^2·\beta^2 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ + \ 1·i \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ A \ ]} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha^2 \ - \ \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \alpha·\beta \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ . $$

The first of this system of equations gives us $ \ \alpha \ = \ \pm \beta \ \ , \ $ which implies that $ \ i \ $ has *two* square-roots, and the second equation gives us $ \ \alpha^2 \ = \ \frac12 \ \Rightarrow \ \alpha \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ $ (we "discard" the equation $ \ \alpha^2 \ = \ -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ $ as we specified this number to be real; but using the imaginary values from this would lead us to redundant results).  We thus have $ \ \alpha \ = \ \pm \beta \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ , \ $ which contains "spurious" values (as often happens when we've "squared" the sides of an algebraic equation).  Testing these in equation $ \ \mathbf{A} \ $ gives us $ \ \sqrt{i} \ = \ \pm   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + i·\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \right) \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2} ·   (1 \ + \ i·1  ) . \ $  This hints at what is to come:   on the Argand plane, $ \ i \ $ lies $ \ 1 \ $ unit from the origin along the imaginary axis, 90º from the real axis, while its two square-roots are each also $ \ 1 \ $ unit from the origin on rays that are $ \ 90º/2 \ = \ 45º \ $ and $ \ (90º + 360º)/2 \ = \ 225º \ $ counter-clockwise from the origin.

Returning to the equation we seek to solve, the second factor  produces
$$ z^2 \ - \ 4·  \frac{1}{\sqrt2} ·   (1 \ + \ i·1  ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z \ \ = \ \ \pm 2 \ · \ \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \ · \ \sqrt{ \ 1 \ + \ 1·i} \quad \quad \mathbf{[ \ B \ ]} $$
(we'll return to the first factor presently).  The complex numbers $ \ \gamma + i·\delta \ $ which represent $ \ \sqrt{ \ 1 \ + \ 1·i} \ $ are found from
$$ \gamma^2 \ - \ \delta^2 \ \ =  \ \  1 \ \ \ , \ \ \ 2·\gamma·\delta \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ ( \ \gamma^2 \ - \ \delta^2 \ )^2 \ \ = \ \ \gamma^4 \ - \ 2·\gamma^2·\delta^2 \ + \ \delta^4 \ \ =  \ \  1 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  \gamma^4 \ - \ 2·\gamma^2·\delta^2 \ + \ ( \ 2·\gamma·\delta \ )^2  + \ \delta^4  \ \ = \ \ \gamma^4 \ + \ 2·\gamma^2·\delta^2 \ + \ \delta^4 $$ $$ = \ \   ( \ \gamma^2 \ + \ \delta^2 \ )^2 \ \  =  \ \  2 \ \ . $$

The consequent system of equations then yields
$$ \gamma^2 \ - \ \delta^2 \ \ =  \ \  1  \ \ \ , \ \ \ \gamma^2 \ + \ \delta^2 \ \ =  \ \  \sqrt2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \gamma^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{ \sqrt2 \ + \ 1}{2} \ \ \ , \ \ \ \delta^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{ \sqrt2 \ - \ 1}{2} \ \ . $$
Again, there are spurious solutions:  checking these against $ \ ( \ \gamma \ + \ i·\delta \ )^2 \ = \ 1 + i \ \ $ gives us
$$ \sqrt{ \ 1 \ + \ i} \ \ = \ \ \pm (\Gamma \ + \ i·\Delta) \ \ , \ \ \text{where} \ \ \Gamma \ = \ + \sqrt{\frac{ \sqrt2 \ + \ 1}{2} } \ \ , \ \ \Delta \ = \ + \sqrt{\frac{ \sqrt2 \ - \ 1}{2} } \ \ . $$
The valid solutions to equation $ \ \mathbf{B} \ $ are then
$$ z \ \ = \ \ \pm 2 \ · \ \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}} \ · \  \left( \    \sqrt{\frac{ \sqrt2 \ + \ 1}{2} }  \ + \ i· \sqrt{\frac{ \sqrt2 \ - \ 1}{2} }  \ \right) \ \ = \ \ \pm ( \    \sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2}    \ + \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2} \ ) \ \ ,  $$
which we can readily see have   magnitude (modulus) $ \ 2 \ \ . $  Going back once more to the original equation, the first factor can be used to write
$$ z^2 \ + \ 4·\sqrt{i} \ \ = \ \ z^2 \ - \ [ \ (-4)·\sqrt{i} \ ] \ \ = \ \ ( \ z \ + \ i·\sqrt{ 4·\sqrt{i} } \ ) \ · \ ( \ z \ - \ i·\sqrt{ 4·\sqrt{i} } \ ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ ,  $$

from which we obtain two distinct solutions, which are the other two fourth-roots of $ \ 16i \ \ , \ $
$$ z \ \ = \ \  \pm \mathbf{i \ ·} \ ( \    \sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2}    \ + \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2} \ ) \ \  = \ \ \pm   \ ( \   - \sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2}    \ + \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2} \ ) \ \ . $$

[This illustrates, incidentally, that multiplication of a complex number by $ \ i \ $ is equivalent to its counter-clockwise rotation by $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ on the Argand plane.]

We at last have the rectangular versions of the four fourth-roots:  but what are these component values?  If one has had to do much calculation of trigonometric values, one may recognize
$$ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \ \sin \left(\frac{\pi/4}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{\frac{1 \ - \ \cos (\pi/4)} {2}} \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{\frac{1 \ - \  \frac{\sqrt2}{2}} {2}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sqrt{ 2 \ - \   \sqrt2}}{2} \ \ , $$
$$ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \  \sqrt{\frac{1 \ + \ \cos (\pi/4)} {2}} \ \ = \ \  \frac{\sqrt{ 2 \ + \   \sqrt2}}{2} \ \ . $$
The various trigonometric co-relations tell us that
$$ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \ -\sin \left(\frac{9 \pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \ \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \  -\cos \left(\frac{13 \pi}{8} \right) $$
and
$$ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \ -\cos \left(\frac{9 \pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \ -\sin \left(\frac{5 \pi}{8} \right) \ \ = \ \  \sin \left(\frac{13 \pi}{8} \right) \ \ . $$

The fourth-roots can then be expressed in polar (trigonometric) form:
$$ z_1 \ = \  \sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2}    \ + \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2} \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \left[ \ \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \ + \ i·\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \  \ \right]  \ \ , $$
$$ z_2 \ = \  -\sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2}    \ + \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2} \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \left[ \ \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi}{8} \right) \ + \ i·\sin \left(\frac{5 \pi}{8} \right) \  \ \right]  \ \ , $$
$$ z_3 \ = \  -\sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2}    \ - \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2} \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \left[ \ \cos \left(\frac{9 \pi}{8} \right) \ + \ i·\sin \left(\frac{9 \pi}{8} \right) \  \ \right]  \ \ , $$
$$ z_4 \ = \  \sqrt{2 \ - \ \sqrt2}    \ - \ i·  \sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt2} \ \ = \ \ 2 \ · \ \left[ \ \cos \left(\frac{13 \pi}{8} \right) \ + \ i·\sin \left(\frac{13 \pi}{8} \right) \  \ \right]  \ \ . $$
(One can of course also write these angles using the equivalence $ \ \theta \ \equiv \ \theta \ \pm \ n·2 \pi \ \ , \ $ with $ \ n \ $ being any natural number.)

It is likely that work along these lines with  algebraic equations and knowledge of Viete's trigonometric solutions to certain polynomial equations that would have led de Moivre to the construction of a formula (which Euler would later prove).

Answer (score -1):

For All complex numbers, $z=a+bi$ we have $|z|=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$ and $\theta=tan^{-1} b/a $ so you have $\theta=tan^{-1} 16/0=\pi/2$